# Unable to read/parse a local json file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse a json file but I am unable to read/parse the data from the file. I prepared the The json data file by copying the contents from a web service call. I copied the contents and saved it in the projects directory. The path to the file is correct.

```
NSError *error;

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"js"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@", filePath);

//    NSInputStream *fileInputStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:filePath];
//    [fileInputStream open];
//    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:fileInputStream options:0 error:&error];
//    NSLog(@"Stream: %@", jsonData);

NSData *fileContents = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", fileContents);
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileContents options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", jsonData);
```

The "fileContents" prints like "20202020 20202020 20202063 6c756249 64203d20" (may be it is hexadecimal value). Why am I getting the data like this? When I parse same date by calling the web service, it works fine.
I have left some commented code here to let you know that I have tried that portion as well.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Any error when you parsing? And your Data.js contains valid JSON data?

Comment: The log output for `fileContents` is perfectly fine. Those are hex values for the data in the file. Each `20` is a space. The `63` is the letter `c`, etc. What is the result of the log for `jsonData`?

Comment: I kept trying on that issue for long and I could not get the solution and finally I had to post it here. Just in few minutes after I posted I found the solution, though it is strange to me why the other solutions didn't work. Here is my code that is working, It may help some one... I don't know how to format the text here, so I have just pasted the code...

Comment: NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"js"];
    
    if(filePath)
    {
        NSLog(@"Path: %@", filePath);
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"JSON_Data: %@", jsonData);
        
        NSArray *list= [jsonData objectForKey:@"states"];
        NSLog(@"states: %@", list);
    }